How to resolve errors in simulating a sigma-delta ADC design in LTspice?
I've been trying to learn how a sigma-delta ADC works. I've been through the block diagram mostly and tried simulating one myself by following this video lecture from "The Signal Path" YouTube channel.  The wiring is right as it shows in the circuit diagram from timestamp 34:30 and it also follows other block diagrams I came across.

I have tried using the D flip-flop as an 1 bit DAC with its 2 values (vhigh and vlow) set between +/- 5V, as said in the video.  Why doesn't this simulation work as intended?  Am I missing something here with reference voltages?  I have included my .asc simulation file as an external link and also copy/pasted the file contents below. Please help me resolve this issue.  Thank you.
Version 4
SHEET 1 1016 680
WIRE -256 -208 -800 -208
WIRE -224 -176 -656 -176
WIRE -288 -112 -592 -112
WIRE -256 -32 -256 -208
WIRE -256 -32 -320 -32
WIRE -192 -32 -256 -32
WIRE 208 16 112 16
WIRE -592 32 -592 -112
WIRE -544 32 -592 32
WIRE -224 32 -224 -96
WIRE -224 32 -240 32
WIRE -656 96 -656 -176
WIRE -544 96 -656 96
WIRE -288 96 -288 -112
WIRE -288 96 -320 96
WIRE -240 96 -240 32
WIRE -240 96 -288 96
WIRE 16 96 -240 96
WIRE 208 128 208 16
WIRE 16 144 16 96
WIRE 176 144 16 144
WIRE -544 160 -624 160
WIRE 272 160 240 160
WIRE 176 176 48 176
WIRE 48 192 48 176
WIRE -624 288 -624 160
WIRE -192 288 -192 -32
WIRE -192 288 -624 288
FLAG -800 -128 0
FLAG 208 192 0
FLAG 112 96 0
FLAG 48 272 0
FLAG -240 160 0
FLAG -544 -32 0
SYMBOL OpAmps\\opamp2 208 96 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMATTR Value lm311
SYMBOL voltage -800 -224 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 9
SYMBOL voltage 112 0 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 9
SYMBOL Misc\\signal 48 176 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value SINE(4.5 1.5 20k)
SYMBOL Misc\\NE555 -432 64 R0
SYMATTR InstName U2
SYMBOL res -240 -192 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 3.5k
SYMBOL cap -256 96 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 1n
TEXT -144 280 Left 2 !.tran 100
TEXT 264 96 Left 2 !.include C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\LTspice\\lib\\sub\\lm311.lib



The diagram you reference in the video doesn't match the simulation you posted at all.  You have a lot of problems going on here, but that would be the first place to start.  I would consider watching the video again and pay attention to what he says about the LM311 comparator output.  You should also post a link to where you got your lm311.lib from.

You have no information on " Why doesn't this simulation work as intended?", how is it intended to work?
